# AWS Full stack app deployment tutorial failed build

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

Following the tutorial on this link: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-intro

Basically, you create a react app with `npx create-react-app`, create a Github repo, connecting and authorizing Github with AWS Amplify console, and then deploying the app.

In the "Deploy your app to AWS amplify" section, I keep getting an error of failed build with this log:

```
                               ## Checking for associated backend environment...
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
                                  npm ERR! Missing: typescript@4.9.5 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
                                    npm
2023-03-04T05:29:24.352Z [WARNING]: ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv@6.12.6 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: ajv-keywords@3.5.2 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR! Missing: json-schema-traverse@0.4.1 from lock file
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Clean install a project
                                    npm
2023-03-04T05:29:24.352Z [WARNING]: ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Usage:
                                    npm ERR! npm ci
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Options:
                                    npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
                                    npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
                                    npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
                                    npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
                                    npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
                                    npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
                                    npm
2023-03-04T05:29:24.353Z [WARNING]: ERR!
                                    npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info
2023-03-04T05:29:24.354Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-03-04T05_29_21_673Z-debug-0.log
2023-03-04T05:29:24.359Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2023-03-04T05:29:24.359Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2023-03-04T05:29:24.359Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-03-04T05:29:24.360Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

This is the Github repo I'm trying to deploy: https://github.com/AsafO7/-amplify-react-graphql

After some googling I've been told to try deleting `my package-lock.json` and `npm install` locally but the build still failed.
I also tried `npm audit fix --force` but the build still failed (note that I'm constantly updating the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files to the repo).
I've been following the instructions of the tutorial to a T, even deleting everything and trying again but to no avail.

Comment: Where actually are you facing the issue in the tutorial? please provide the step and your github repo if possible.

Comment: I've provided a link to the repo now.
Like I said in the post, the issue is in the "Deploy your app to AWS amplify" section, it occurs on instruction F.
Instead of building and deploying successfully, the error above is produced.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the repository, please try this one and see if you can deploy. Fork https://github.com/kasukur/amplify-react-graphql and then try to deploy in amplify hosting.

Comment: I just tried the tutorial with this repository https://github.com/kasukur/react-amplify and it seems to be working https://main.di7v2pdbqza73.amplifyapp.com/

Comment: I'm trying to deploy the forked repo but it's asking for to create an environment and a new service role? Why do I suddenly need those?

Comment: I managed to deploy my repo after I copied the `package-lock.json` file from your repo.
I don't know why mine was missing things after following their instructions, but the problem is solved and I'm moving on.
Thank you so much Sri!

Comment: you need to select the branch and choose the service role. it is common sometimes to see that as mandatory fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package-lock.json` seems to be the issue in the original repo.
use the `package-lock.json` from https://github.com/kasukur/react-amplify